# Can't fit a logistic regression model for the Iris dataset

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

Trying to make a logistic regression model work on the iris dataset, but it isn't fitting. What's wrong with the code. Thank You..

```
# Dependencies used: numpy, matpotlib.pyplot, csv
# dataset: Iris
# Binary classification using gradient descent
# python 3.5
# input data matrix = x(99 X 1) # including ones vector
# discrete output data matrix = y(99 X 1)
# parameters matrix = theta(5 X 1)

for j in range(3500):
    # hypothesis function
    h = 1/(1 + np.exp(-x.dot(theta)))

    # gradient descent
    theta = theta - (0.00001/m) * np.sum(x.T.dot(h - y)) + (30.0/m)*np.sum(np.sum(theta[1:5, :]**2))

    # cost function
    cost = -(1/m) * np.sum(y.T.dot(np.log(h)) + (1-y).T.dot(np.log(1-h)))
    j_iter.append(cost)
    Iter.append(j)
```

[image: This is the graph [image]]

Comment: This lacks [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Iris dataset contains three output classes which means your code should perform multinomial regression. Mostly binomial regression is the adopted one in several tools which means the input dataset must contain only two output classes. Please cross-check whether your code handles three classes or not and then proceed... This may be ur issue.